# Why isn't this image showing?

Tags: html, css

I made a header image, but for some reason I can't get it to appear from CSS.

Here's a screenshot: 
[image]

The header is in the same image directory as the index.html file. The background image is appearing, but not this header. I typed the header twice in the HTML as a div to test it in two different spots to see if it is working, but for some reason it is not showing up, I don't get it lol.

Thanks.

```
#header {
        background-image:url('../emailheader.png');
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;

 } 

<div id="header"></div>
```

Here's an [example](http://tinkerbin.com/gjdynAaX) of it. But I am not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly not the problem, but you have two elements that have the same id. Ids must be unique.

Comment: Also, please post the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Where is the image? `emailheader.png`

Comment: @sab, You have used two elements using same id `header` Id is unique and shouldn't be duplicated within the page.

Comment: it is not a problem with the id using header. look at the tinkerbin i just uploaded, there is only one in there

Comment: You are using `height: 100%` - but this will only work if a parent element has a defined height. Try setting a `min-height: Xpx` where x is the height of your image

Comment: @sab: you need to learn difference between css ids `#` and classes `.` You must see this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/MA2TNI7r)**

You need provide **height** OR it will be dependent on the height of the inner content, which **0**

```
 #header {
            background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/ncTiy.png');
            width:100%;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            height:200px;
     }
```

Answer (score 9):

Since there's no content in the div its height is zero, so you don't see anything. Add some content to the div or add a `height` or `min-height` to the CSS.

`height:100%` doesn't work because it sets the element's height to equal that of its parent, and the parent's (`#container`) height is not set.

See http://tinkerbin.com/QDAEuDUA.

Comment: thank you for your help. the other guy answered first so i selected him out of fairness, but thank u again for paying attention

Answer (score 1):

It's cause you're using 100% height and 100% width. Just change it to px values.

Answer (score 1):

```
#header {
    background-image:url('../emailheader.png');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

}

```
html{height:100%;}

body{height:100%;}
```

May work without the content in the div#header or put some content to the div or use 
min-height ,it will work.

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

On seing the screenshot of the code. I found two problems.

1. There is **NO** stylesheet attached on the first place
2. `header` is used to identify two different elements. (Also mentioned by [Blaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239454/295264))

However, the main **reason** why it is not showing up in tinkerbin, is because the `div` neither contains any elements nor has a fixed dimensions. Check [this](http://tinkerbin.com/uamF1EjW) update of your bin.

Comment: yes there is a style sheet. look at http://tinkerbin.com/gjdynAaX , it shows only one id header

Comment: you better check who is downvoting you because i didnt do it

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to do it

Comment: @sab, Oh, I am sorry. I seem to have over reacted. But I dont understand why someone would downvote without a reason. Anyways, did my solution worked? Or is there anything I can help you with.

Comment: WHAT is WRONG in this answer? Please THE MIGHTY DOWNVOTER tell me.